# XGBoostRegressor outputs warning about parameters that might not be used

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, xgboost

Im doing a model with XGBRegressor with multiple outputs:

```py
from xgboost import XGBRegressor
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputRegressor

XBC = XGBRegressor(booster = 'gbtree',learning_rate =0.01,
n_estimators=5000,early_stopping_rounds=50,
evals= [X_test,Y_test],max_depth=5,gamma=0.1,eval_metric="rmse")

classifier_XBC = MultiOutputRegressor(XBC)

classifier_XBC.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

> WARNING: C:/Users/Administrator/workspace/xgboost-win64_release_1.4.0/src/learner.cc:573:
> Parameters: { "early_stopping_rounds", "evals" } might not be used.

> This may not be accurate due to some parameters are only used in language bindings but
> passed down to XGBoost core.  Or some parameters are not used but slip through this
> verification. Please open an issue if you find above cases.

My code is outputting the warning above, however, it is running with no errors. I checked all the parameters in the xgboost documentation. What does it means? Has anyone had this issue before??